# Como puedo listar un unico usuario

Tags: python

El codigo es muy sencillito, tengo todas las demas funciones pero no se como hacer que liste un unico usuario con este codigo

```
 usuarios[id] = nombre, direct, tel, correo, fecha
def listar(): #definimos la funcion de listar
global usuarios #definimos global para poder usar la variable usuarios
for user in usuarios: #recorremos nuestros usuarios
    print(
    """
            ID: {}
            Nombre: {}
            Direccion: {}
            Correo: {}
            Fecha: {}
    """ .format(user, usuarios[user][0],user, usuarios[user][1],user, usuarios[user][2]) 
    )
usuarios = {}
try:
    option = int(input("\n Selecciona una opcion: "))

    if option == 1:
        agregar_usuario()
    elif option == 2:
        id = int(input("Ingrese el NIF: "))
        delete()
    elif option == 3:
        id = int(input("Ingrese el NIF del usuario:"))
        listar(id)
    elif option == 4:
        listar()
    elif option == 5:
        print(input("¿Es cliente habitual?"))
        listar()
    elif option == 6:
        break
    else:
        print("Marque una opcion correcta en el menu")
except:
    print("Por favor ingrese datos válidos")
```

En la opcion 4 del try listo todos los usuarios pero no se como hacer que liste un único usuario

Comment: Como estas guardando al usuario?

Answer (score 0):

La solución estándar para estos casos es tener dos funciones: una que lista un usuario y una segunda que los liste todos recurriendo a la primera:

```
def listar_id(user):
    print(
        """
                ID: {}
                Nombre: {}
                Direccion: {}
                Correo: {}
                Fecha: {}
        """.format(user, usuarios[user][0], usuarios[user][1], usuarios[user][2], usuarios[user][3])
    )

def listar(): #definimos la funcion de listar
    for user in usuarios: #recorremos nuestros usuarios
        listar_id(user)
```

Con eso, el cuerpo del ciclo queda así:

```
...
elif option == 3:
    id = int(input("Ingrese el NIF del usuario:"))
    listar_id(id)
elif option == 4:
    listar()
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ha sido de gran utilidad